Largest angle of a triangle,
If the measure of $\angle EVU$ = 60, and segment $\overline{OE}\cong\overline{OU}$, and the measure of $\angle VOE$ is greater than the measure of $\angle VOU$, then the largest angle of $\triangle UVE$ is $\angle$ ?
enter image description here
I managed to find that $\overline{VE} > \overline{VU}$, but I don't know what to do with the angle $\angle EVU$.

I would recommend that the image be made to scale... EVU looks a lot smaller than 60 degrees.

I initially believed that the angle VUE was the largest, but I wasn't clear about the significance of the angle EVU. The reason why VE is greater than VU is due to the Side-Angle-Side inequality theorem. Since OE equals OU and the angle VOE is larger than the angle VOU, it follows that VE must be greater than VU.

Alright, two parts:
First, note that $\overline{VE} > \overline{VU}$. We are given that $\angle VOE > \angle VOU$, and as $\overline{VO} = \overline{VO}$ and $\overline{EO} = \overline{OU}$ this means by law of cosines, $\overline{VE} > \overline{VU}$.
Now, the rest: From part 1, clearly $\triangle EVU$ is not equilateral. It is a well known fact that in a triangle, if one side is greater than another, the angle facing the greater side is greater than the angle facing the smaller side. Thus, we have $\angle EUV > \angle VEU$, and clearly $\angle EUV > 60^{\circ}$ so the largest angle should be $\angle EUV. $
